# what is the meaning of a double pointer of struct in C

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct

I have a problem understanding this structure , would love to get a clear explanation.

```
typedef struct exp{
   int x;
   struct exp *parent;
   struct exp **children;
}
```

what does it mean the parent and the children ?
"parent" is an array of this structure?
and what is the meaning of the children ? it's an array of arrays?!
I really can't understand..

and last thing, If I'm adding an element , it becomes a specific child of some parent, how can I reach all the children of a parent? shouldn't it be a structure "List" (using next etc .. ? )?

thank you!!

Comment: Do you know what pointers are?

Comment: yes, but I can't understand if the "children" is an array of arrays ? or pointer to pointer to array... I'm new in C , used Java till now

Comment: It is a pointer to pointer to struct exp. It points to a pointer, possibly the first member of an array of pointers. Also, there should be a semicolon after the struct definition. And since it is a typedef, you also need to add a name for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This image shows a possible scenario:

[image: a possible scenario]

It was obtained using this code and [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct exp{
    int x;
    struct exp *parent;
    struct exp **children;
};

int main ()
{
    struct exp *x = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    x->x = 42;
    x->parent = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    x->children = calloc(5, sizeof(x->children[0]));
    x->children[0] = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    x->children[2] = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    x->children[3] = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    x->children[4] = calloc(1, sizeof(x[0]));
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, the `children` field is a vector of pointers to `struct exp`. You decide how many  elements to put there and the other things.

PS: Code is only a demo, it has not quite a good quality.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pointer to a pointer, which in that case seems to be used as a list of `struct exp`.

Each `struct exp` has a reference to it's "parent", and a pointer to a list of children `struct exp`.

```
typedef struct exp{
    int x;
    struct exp *parent;
    struct exp **children;
} element;

// create ROOT elemnt
element * root = (element*) malloc(sizeof(element)); //alocate mem. for 1 element
```

Once we have a "root" we can add children, following is pseudo-code

```
for 1 to 10{
    child = new element;
    child->parent = root;                // tell the child who is his parent
    addToRoot( root , child);            // call a function that inserts elemnts to root

}
```

So now we should have `root` with a list of 10 elements:

```
_______________                                    _______________   
|             | (children)                         |             | - (parent) points to struct exp, root
|     root    | - points to list of struct exp  -> |   child 0   |   
|             |                                    |             | - (children) points to null; // if it's empty  
_______________                                    _______________ 

                                                   _______________  
                                                   |             | - (parent) points to struct exp, root
                                                   |   child 1   |     
                                                   |             | - (children) points to null; // if it's empty 
                                                   _______________ 

                                                   _______________  
                                                   |             | - (parent) points to struct exp, root 
                                                   |   child 2   |      
                                                   |             | - (children) points to null; // if it's empty  
                                                   _______________ 

                                                   _______________  
                                                   |             | - (parent) points to struct exp, root 
                                                   |   child 3   |      
                                                   |             | - (children) points to null; // if it's empty  
                                                   _______________ 

                                                         .
                                                         .
                                                         . 

                                                   _______________  
                                                   |             | - (parent) points to struct exp, root 
                                                   |   child 9   |      
                                                   |             | - (children) points to null; // if it's empty  
                                                   _______________
```

Something like that... Did it help?

Answer (score 1):

It's an array of pointers to child nodes- this looks like some kind of tree structure.

There is a parent node for each node, and each node has one or more children. You can travel from a parent to one of its children with

```
expInstance->children[i];
```

Where i is a number indicating one of the child nodes.  It's not really clear how many child nodes there are from this definition- it could be one, or two, or a million.  But given that information you could loop through them.  Either with

```
for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_CHILDREN_NODES;i++){
    expInstance->children[i];
}
```

if you know the length of the array in advance or the somewhat strange

```
while(expInstance.children[i++]){
    expInstance->children[i];
}
```

(There are a couple variously clever ways to do this, but there has to be the assumption built into the structure that there will be a null pointer in the last slot of this array in order to terminate it.)

Comment: How you you loop through the childrens? You cannot stop at a `NULL` value (see example in my answer). You do need to know more than the provided code offers (either that the only place where we have a `NULL` is the end of the vector or the number of elements or the value of a specific element designated as terminator)

Comment: Right, that's why I said  given that information you could loop through them.

Comment: That's why I asked you the question: you cannot loop safely without the extra bit of information :)

Comment: Now it is better. Though there are other versions too.

PS: sorry for nitpicking but since you asked for an accept vote... :)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing more code. Are you trying to implement a tree? From this definition, this is what apparent to me:

- parent points to the parent node of this structure.
- children points to the array of pointers of all its child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remember that a structure cannot contain an instance of itself.  IOW, you cannot do something like

```
struct exp {
  int x;
  struct exp parent;
  ...
};
```

The main reason for this is that the struct type is not *complete* at the point where you try to declare the `parent` member; since you haven't finished describing the type yet, the compiler doesn't know how big the `parent` member should be.  Not to mention that the `parent` member would itself have a `parent` member of type `struct exp`, which would in turn have a `parent` member of type `struct exp`, which would in turn have a `parent` member of type `struct exp`, etc., etc., etc., etc.  You'd wind up with an object that required an infinite amount of storage.

So you cannot have a member of type `struct exp`.  However, you *can* have a **pointer** to an object of type `struct exp`; you can create pointers to *incomplete* types, and all struct pointer types have the same size and representation (IOW, `struct foo *pf` and `struct bar *pb` will have the same size, even if `struct foo` and `struct bar` do not).

So the `parent` member is (probably) only meant to point to a single instance of type `struct exp` (each instance of `struct exp` has one parent).  Likewise the `children` member is (probably) meant to be a single-dimensioned array of pointers to `struct exp` (each instance of `atruct exp` can have zero, one, or more children).